# Simplify Nested Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a problem with nested lists. For example, i have this list:

```
solution = {{{{{18, 11, 8}, {17, 12, 2}}, {{17, 12, 11}, {18, 8, 2}}}, {{{{17, 11, 8}, {18, 12, 2}}, {{18, 12, 8}, {17, 11, 2}}}, {{18, 12, 11}, {17, 8, 2}}}}, {{18, 17}, {12, 11, 8, 2}}}
```

I would like to simplify this nested list into list of lists:

```
simplified = {{{18, 11, 8}, {17, 12, 2}} , {{17, 12, 11}, {18, 8, 2}}, ...}
```

How can it be done? I used some `ArrayFlatten`, but this didn't help me.

Thank you for solution, i am trying to understand this language.

Comment: Please add the "rules" by which the list is transformed. Readers should not have to decode the meaning from the example.

Comment: In the process of `Nest` you can add `Flatten` to avoid too many {}, rewrite your oiginal code.

Comment: `Flatten[solution, 2]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Cases[solution, {{__Integer}..}, All]
```

> ```
> {{{18, 11, 8}, {17, 12, 2}}, {{17, 12, 11}, {18, 8, 2}},
>  {{17, 11, 8}, {18, 12, 2}}, {{18, 12, 8}, {17, 11, 2}}, 
>  {{18, 12, 11}, {17, 8, 2}}, {{18, 17}, {12, 11, 8, 2}}}
> ```

If the target lists contain exactly two sublists of integers, you can also use

```
Partition[#, 2] & @ Cases[solution, {__Integer}, All]
```

**Update:** Few additional methods:

```
Level[solution, {-3}]

Fold[FlattenAt, solution, {1, 2, 2, 1}] (* inspired by cvgmt's answer *)

Fold[Delete, solution, Thread[{{1, 2, 2, 1}, 0}]]

Fold[MapAt[Splice,##]&, solution, {1, 2, 2, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

It must be have an elegant way which I could not found at that moment.

```
solution = {{{{{18, 11, 8}, {17, 12, 2}}, {{17, 12, 11}, {18, 8, 2}}}, {{{{17, 11, 8}, {18, 12, 2}}, {{18, 12, 8}, {17, 11, 2}}}, {{18, 12, 11}, {17, 8, 2}}}}, {{18, 17}, {12, 11, 8, 2}}};
solution//TreeForm
simplified =FlattenAt[1]@
  FlattenAt[2]@FlattenAt[2]@FlattenAt[1]@solution
simplified//TreeForm
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get rid of the two outermost braces. This can simply be done by:

```
solution = {{{{{18, 11, 8}, {17, 12, 2}}, {{17, 12, 11}, {18, 8, 2}}}, {{{{17, 11, 8}, {18, 12, 2}}, {{18, 12, 8}, {17, 11, 2}}}, {{18, 12, 11}, {17, 8, 2}}}}, {{18, 17}, {12, 11, 8, 2}}}

Flatten[solution, 2 ]
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you show the actual `code` that could be used, in a code-block, along with a depiction (usually the output of the code being ran) of the result of using said `code`.